# Find id of panel at active index accordian bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

If i want to retrieve index of active panel of the accordion in bootstrap i use the following.

```
var index = $('#accordion .in').parent().index();
```

How could retrieve the 'id' of this active panel?

regards

Comment: $('#accordion .in').parent().attr("id")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use jquery [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) of the format `attr("id")`

```
var id = $('#accordion .in').parent().attr("id");
```

Comment: Awesome thanks. Just a final question. if I want to get the 'id' at index 0 for example, how would I do this?

Comment: @Arianule can you explain a little more? It will be better if you can provide the html.

Comment: I think I have got it, apologies...Thanks again for help